# error in over-riding the function c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, event-handling, overriding

Hello guys I need to ask that why can't I override this add function it gives an error that it must return some value and when I try to return some value like this "return base.Add(o);" it says that the add function return a void so a return statement should not come. Please tell me what am I doing wrong

```
class MyArrayList : ArrayList
{
    public event EventHandler Added;
    public void onAdded()
    {
        EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
        Added(this, e);
    }

    public override add(object o )
    {
        onAdded();
        base.Add(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public override int add(object o)`

Comment: FYI You need to check that your `Added` event is not null before calling it in your `onAdded` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `int`. You're missing a return type:

```
public override Add(object o)
{
    onAdded();
    base.Add(o);
}
```

should be:

```
public override int Add(object o)
{
    onAdded();
    base.Add(o);
}
```

This looks like a learning experiment, but if it's not, consider looking into the type safe generic collections introduced in .NET 2.0, such as [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing return type int the function. See below:

```
public override int Add(object o)
{
    onAdded();
    base.Add(o);
}
```